# VB6 executable icons

Tags: vb6, icons

I have quite a large VB6 project, with many forms, classes, modules and user controls.

When I create a shortcut to the compiled executable and choose "change icon" for the shortcut there are multiple icons that I can select from. This indicates that there are multiple icon resources being compiled into the executable. The first icon is the "normal" application icon which seems to be controlled by setting the icon form in the MAKE tab of the project settings. That is fine and works as expected.

The problem I have is that I just cannot find out where the other icons that are being compiled into the executable are coming from. Is there a way I can take a VB6 project or a Complied executable and find out where in the project the icons resources are being set?

I've checked all the forms and a bunch of the image lists and none seem to be the icons in question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2004/08/17/VB_icons.html?page=3) link talks about using the VB6 add-in manager to use an add-in called the VB6 Resource Editor.  Sounds like a good place to check for more resources.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is that I just
>   cannot find out where the other icons
>   that are being compiled into the
>   executable are coming from.

I believe this is a misapprehension.

The default set of alternate icons for a shortcut are held within Shell32.dll.

Comment: No in my case they were indeed in a compiled resource file, I was just unaware of the resource file in the VB6 project. As soon as I opened the resource editor it pointed out that the project contained a compiled resource file and it was the source of my icons. That's the trouble with inheriting legacy applications.